# Display array of emails without trim - es6

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

let's say I have an array of emails like this

```
emails = [ 'guest1@gmail.com' , 'guest2@email.com' , 'guest3@email.com', 'guest3@email.com']
```

**Expected result** :display full emails in a header where only maximum character allowed is 60 ، so if there's 3 emails more than the allowed character we display the two of them and ignore the rest .

**I tried** the following but i'm stuck with the rest

```
public summarizeEmails() {
    let numberOfRecipents: string = '';
    let max_char: number = 60;
    let numberOfChar: number;

    let otherRecipients =  this.emails
        .filter(p => p.email !== this.profile.email)
        .map(p => p.fullNameOrEmail().length)


        console.log(otherRecipients);
}
```

Comment: Can't get your question. What you want in the output exactly.

Comment: display full emails to maximum 60 character , so for example if there's 2 emails which are 50 character and the third email is 30 character , we output the first two emails without something like that "guest3@......"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a regular for loop:

```
 let result = "";
 for(const [index, email] of emails.entries()) {
  if(result.length + email.length > 60) {
    result += "+" + (emails.length - index);
    break;
  }

  result += email + " ";
 }
```

Comment: well if the characters more than 60 , i basically want to display the emails without trim them like that 'guest1@.... " just display full email and ignore the rest of the characters

Comment: Thanks works fine :) 
my question was how to display the length of the rest of the emails .. +2 emails left in array for example :)

Comment: result += "+" + (emails.length - index ); that worked fine without -1

Comment: Hi Jonas , i'm trying to use forEach instead of for of , any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: @Amr.Ayoub why?! you can't break a `.forEach` loop therefore it is the wrong tool here

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, checking the length the final string would have if you added the email.

```js
const emails = [ 'guest1@gmail.com' , 'guest2@email.com' , 'guest3@email.com', 'guest3@email.com'];

const newEmails = emails.reduce((acc, val) => `${acc.join('')}${val}`.length < 60 ? acc.concat(val) : acc, []);

console.log(newEmails);
```